# Advice on structuring custom exception types

Tags: java, exception

I am unsure how best to structure custom exceptions.  Say i have a situation where there's some library that throws its own custom exception class, with a custom field in it:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
  private final String additionalInfo;

  public CustomException(String message, String additional) {
    super(message);
    this.additionalInfo = additional;
  } 

  public String getAdditionalInfo() {
    return additionalInfo;
  }
}
```

Dealing with this is pretty straightforward:

```
try {
  something();
} catch (CustomException e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
  LOGGER.error(e.getAdditionalInfo());
}
```

So far, so good, but what about when this is wrapped up many layers deep into some sort of service and handled in this way:

```
// in a subclass of a theoretical ServiceHandler interface
public void handle() throws OperationFailedException {
  try {
    something();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw new OperationFailedException("The operation failed.", e);
  }
}
```

Further down the callstack the service dispatch code catches this new exception, returns the generic (safe) message to the external caller, and logs the full exception trace somewhere internal, including the cause (our original custom exception type).  The problem now is that the extra field in CustomException has gone missing from the logs, because the logging framework is only interested in `getMessage()` and the callstack.

```
try { // call to the ServiceHandler
  sendResponseToClient(findServiceHandler(rpcName).handle(args));
} catch (Throwable th) { 
  LOGGER.error(th);
  sendErrorToClient("An internal error occurred with incident ID: <id>");
}
```

I can think of a few of solutions:

**1)** Make the thing that logs the service exceptions aware of this special exception type so it can log it

**2)** Override `getMessage()` so it returns `super.getMessage() + getAdditionalInfo()`

**3)** Everywhere something is called that could throw one of these i rethrow it as something else with the additional field baked into the message:

```
try { 
  something();
} catch (CustomException ce) {
  throw new OperationFailedException("The operation failed because " + ce.getAdditionalInfo(), ce);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  throw new OperationFailedException("The operation failed", e);
}
```

The actual use case is a native code library with a few hundred functions, and they're called literally everywhere throughout this app.  This exception type is a general "the api has failed in an unexepected way" error, so it's unchecked, and in day to day operation i wouldn't expect to ever see one.

**(1)** seems like it's easy to miss out new types in future, if in a year's time someone adds another custom exception type they need to be aware of all places that might log it and write the corresponding handler code there.  **(2)** feels a little fishy, since you'd be creating an exception with one message, and getting a different message back.  Applying the pattern in **(3)** to it seems like it will produce a lot of clutter, particularly if i have a couple of these custom exception types to worry about.

Which approach should i use?  Are there other options, or would you recommend restructuring something to get around this?

Comment: Why don't you just put the extra info in the message? Or if that is not possible, I would go for 2)

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two cases for an exception:

1) You can recover

2) You can't, you just want your application to exit

If you can recover, you may want to think about using a checked exception.
Then you **have** to deal with the exception and the compiler will tell you where to catch it.

Otherwise, if the application just crashes you may want to add this additional info to the message you're giving to the superclass constructor.